# Base of vector space $C([a,b], f)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $ C[a, b] = F:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ continuous functions.

Let $ \beta = \lbrace 1, x, x ^ {2}, x ^ {3}, ... \rbrace $ (with infinite elements), prove that $ \beta $ is not the basis of the space $ C [a, b ] $.

To do this, it must be shown that one of the following is not true:

1. $ \beta $ is a generator set.
2. $ \beta $ is linearly independent.

In section 1. take the function $ f(x) = nx $, $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that:

$ f (x) = \lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} x + \lambda_{3} x^{2}+... $

$ \Rightarrow nx= \lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} x + \lambda_{3} x^{2}+... $

$\Rightarrow \lambda_{1} =0, \lambda_{2}=n, \lambda_{3}=0, \lambda_{4}=0,...$

But, $ \lambda_{2} = n $ is not unique, therefore it does not generate $f$.

Is this test correct for 1.?

How can I test section 2.?

Comment: a set B of vectors in a vector space V is called a basis if every element of V may be written in a unique way as a *finite* linear combination of elements of B

Comment: It is not a base. As Tanner pointed: every element of V must be a (finite) linear combination of vectors of $\beta$. Can you write, for example, the exponential function as a finite linear combination?

Comment: I don't think you are talking about vector spaces, because of @J.W.Tanner 's comment. You want to allow countably many coefficients. Anyway, take some analytical function that has a singularity at $s$ so that $|s-a|<|b-a|$. An example is: $\frac{1}{(x-a)^2+\frac{(a-b)^2}{4}}$.

Comment: I think I know that $ \beta $ is not a generator set, but is linearly independent. I can see it in particular examples, but I can't get a proof as such.

Comment: And please, take away the "algebraic-topology" tag, because it isn't any algebraic topology hah

Comment: For 1: The function $\exp : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ cannot be written as a linear combination of elements in $\beta$, for if there exists $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ and $c_0,\dots,c_n \in \mathbb R$ such that $$(\forall x \in [a,b]) \quad e^x = c_0+c_1x+\cdots+c_nx^n;$$ taking the $(n+1)$-th derivative we get that $e^x = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, which is clearly false.

Comment: If they were linearly dependent, then there would be a set of coefficients (not all zero) $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \ldots$ such that $\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x + \ldots = 0$. So you just have to prove that there's no power series that is constantly $0$ on the interval $[a, b]$.

Comment: I took the liberty of deleting the "algebraic topology" tag, since it is arguably not at all accurate...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not really know what you consider a basis. But *clearly*, $nx \in \mathrm{span}\lbrace \beta \rbrace$. Just look again.

If you mean basis in an approximation sense, then consider [Stone-Weierstraß-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

If you mean it in a finite-dimensional sense, then your question boils down to whether all functions in $C[a, b]$ are polynomials. But they clearly are not: Note that for any polynomial $p$, if $k := \mathrm{deg}(p)$, then its $k+1$-st derivative vanishes. But for $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) := \exp(x)$ then $f^{(n)}(x) = \exp(x) \neq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.